# Apply New Font to application Android

Tags: android, android-layout, fonts

i'm try apply new font in my applcation android and can call from style.xml

eg. my font is  in assets/thaoma.ttf

style.xml

```
<style name="text_black_color_bold" >
        <item name="android:textColor">#3E3E3E</item>
        <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
        <item name="android:typeface"></item> /* call new font here */
    </style>
```

Comment: No you can't do that. You can only set default android fonts.

Comment: how this apply new font ? thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can't include it from xml.  You have to do it through code like so:

```
final TextView myTextView = getTextView();
final AssetManager assets = ctx.getAssets();
final Typeface font = Typeface.createFromAsset(assets, "thamoa.ttf");
setTypeface(font);
```

One nifty trick is to extend TextView and auto-apply the font at runtime.

```
public class CustomTextView extends TextView {

    public CustomTextView(Context ctx) {
        super(ctx);
        setupText(ctx);
    }

    public CustomTextView(Context ctx, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(ctx, attrs);
        setupText(ctx);
    }

    public CustomTextView(Context ctx, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(ctx, attrs, defStyle);
        setupText(ctx);
    }

    private void setupText(Context ctx) {
        // check if in edit mode and return. Fonts can't be applied when viewing from editor
        if(isInEditMode()) {
           return;
        }

        final AssetManager assets = ctx.getAssets();
        final TypeFace font = Typeface.createFromAsset(assets, "thamoa.ttf");
        setTypeface(font);
    }
}
```

Then you can use it the same way, but refer to it like so in xml:

```
<package.containing.class.CustomTextView
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   <!-- whatever attributes that would normally apply here -->
 />
```

Comment: I recommend you make a utility class that will load your typefaces once and store them with SoftReferences, and then have your custom view access the fonts that way. Here's an example of someone doing it (I made some modifications for my own project, but its a start): http://helpmeco.de/2012/2/custom-fonts-in-android-widgets

Answer (score 0):

If you want to set this custom font to the entire app, and I think that's your case, create an assets directory and put your customefont.ttf file inside that directory.

After that, you need this lib compile it in your grade file

```
complie'me.anwarshahriar:calligrapher:1.0'
```

and use it in the onCreate method in the main activity

```
Calligrapher calligrapher = new Calligrapher(this);
calligrapher.setFont(this, "yourCustomFontHere.ttf", true);
```

This is the most elegant super fast way to do that.